# Multi-Language resources for wpf user control

Tags: wpf, vb.net, user-controls, resourcebundle

I am building a wpf user control to provide navigation facilities for database records.

[image]

The control is provided with a set of default images (as illustrated above) which the end user can change is they so wish.  In addition the end user can choose to dispense with images altogether.  In the event that they select that option (for either one or all of the buttons that comprise the control) I have provided some default fallback text.

[image]

This text can also be overwritten by the end user if they so wish, but the default text at least provides them with some basic text that essentially conveys what the button does and saves them having to add text every time they use the control (default tooltip text is also provided).

Now if you happen to speak English, or your intended target audience is English this should work, but it doesn't really cater as is for languages other than English.  This I would now like to change.

What reading I've done on the subject of multi-lingual resources and wpf seems to assume that one is talking about the overall application rather than a standalone user control that might be used in different language environments.

I had a talk with a creator of controls who said that making this multilingual would probably involve building several copies of the control for each intended language.

In the light of this I have two questions.  Was the gentleman I spoke to correct, should I in fact build multiple copies of this for each language, of is there a way to have multi-language resources within the same copy of the user control?

If the latter is possible what is the correct way to go about achieving this. We will be dealing in total with default texts for eleven buttons (which I will need to be able to refer to in code within the control incidentally) and default texts for thirteen tooltips (which again will need to be able to be referred to within the code of the control).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on [WPF localization extension](https://github.com/SeriousM/WPFLocalizationExtension).

Here's a pretty good documentation for it: [link](https://wpflocalizeextension.codeplex.com/documentation).

You can define your controls' localizable properties, which store their localized values in the satellite resource assemblies.

In your xaml code, define the localized properties with xaml extensions syntax:

```
<Button Content="{lex:Loc Test}" />
```

Then, create resource files for each culture your application will support and give them the same name as the main assembly plus the general or specific culture code (e.g. *en-US*, *de*, *de-AT*, ...) before the **.resx** ending yielding: *AssemblyName.CultureCode.resx.*

Now, populate the resource files with your localized properties key/value pairs and build the project.

You're done!